# Loading a class in contribution of an ExtensionPoint

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've to retrieve a class from an extension point I made. My goal is to export a file from my UI plugin using an externalized export plugin.

- My plugin A (UI) is just using the `Export` class of B has a service.
- My plugin B (export plugin) has an ExtensionPoint. One of it's attribute is **ExportClass**, required, and requesting a class implementing an `IExport` class.
- My plugin C (export in XML format), has an extension to A's extensionPoint. With a class implementing `IExport`as **ExportClass** attribute called `ExportXML`.

My service class `Export` won't load `ExportXML` class and I don't know why. I checked dependencies, Bundle-Path, added my org.jdom depency too in build.properties file. But still, I've no idea because every time I try to launch the export it fails loading the class with error :

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plugin C was unable to load class C.ExportXML
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
>   [...]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C.ExportXML cannot be found by C_1.0.0.qualifier
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:448)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:361)

I'm a bit speechless because I can't find where the error is comming from.
The function I used to retrieve the `ExportXML` class in the plugin B is :

```
IExport exportClass = null;
for(IConfigurationElement contribution : this.getContributions()){
    if(contribution.getAttribute(Export_ExtensionPoint_Attribute_formatExtension).equals(formatExtension)){
        Object o;
        try {
            o = contribution.createExecutableExtension(Export_ExtensionPoint_Attribute_exportClass);
        if(o instanceof IExport)
            exportClass = (IExport) o;
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is C *plugin.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         id="C"
         point="B">
      <exportFormat
            ExportClass="C.ExportXML"
            formatExtension="xml"
            formatName="XML">
      </exportFormat>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

And here my `ExportXML` header in C:

```
package C;
public class ExportXML implements IExport {
...
}
```

**Note :** I can get the attribute formatExtension as I enter in the try, just the creatExecutableExtension method is failing.

build.properties file :

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               icons/,\
               lib/jdom-2.0.6.jar
```

MANIFEST.MF :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: XML Export
Bundle-SymbolicName: fr.enseeiht.waldo.tools.export.xml;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: fr.enseeiht.waldo.tools.export.xml.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: Waldo
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 fr.enseeiht.waldo.tools.analyzer;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 fr.enseeiht.waldo.tools.export;bundle-version="1.0.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Plugin structure :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EeI6.png

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It is looking for a class `ExportXML` in a **package** of `C` in plugin `C` - is the class really in a package called `C`?

Comment: Yes, is it bad ?

Comment: It isn't a great name, package names are lower case by convention, but as long as it is correct I suppose it is OK. Is that the whole of the error message, I would expect a 'Caused by' section as well?

Comment: Oh you meant if "C" was the name of the plugin and the package ? No it's not I just modified it to clarifly my example. But my file is in a package having the plugin's name ^^
I just added the caused by section in the topic, thank you

Comment: Oh my god I just discovered the "qualifier" name has a mispell, I've certainly mispelled the name of the package somewhere (it's kind of a looooong package name ...) Gonna check if the error is comming from that, but that's certainly is

Comment: Argh, no it's not, the package name was mispelled so it's not comming from this :/

Comment: You have told Eclipse that the class is in a package of `C`, if it is something else you have declared this incorrectly in the extension point. Show us the package declaration in the class and the extension point in the plugin.xml

Comment: Mmmh, What do you mean by Package declaration ? I can't find the information. Oh, you just meant the ``` package C.xml``` it's fine, about the plugin extension point should I show the .exsd ? (sorry if can't answer before tommorow :/ )

Comment: No I mean the `package x.y.z;` at the top of the ExportXML.java and I mean the usage of the extension point in the C plugin's plugin.xml.

Comment: Ok @greg-449, I added it. Thank you for your help btw :)

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, but Eclipse can't find the class. Make sure you are specifying `-clean` on the Eclipse start. Also note that some code in Eclipse expects plugin ids to have at least one '.' in them and may misbehave if they don't.

Comment: Ok, I got a part of the problem. When I run my `ExportXML` class as I run my `Export` class, Eclipse do not find it neither and I get a Java.lang.NoClassDefFound exception. I tryed using the -clean arguement in my eclipse but it didn't work. 

I'm gonna rewrite the plugin containing the ExportXML Class. I think there is nothing I can do for now :/

Comment: It sounds like there is something seriously wrong with your plugin's structure. Show us the folder structure of the plugin, the MANIFEST.MF and the build.properties. Exactly what folder is the ExportXML.java in.

Comment: Do you think the problem could come from my use of jdom and how am I declaring the library ? 
I currently did put the jdom jar in a /lib folder, and my built properties are this :
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               icons/,\
               lib/jdom-2.0.6.jar

(Sorry I didn't see your post while sending this comment)

Comment: I did send a picture of the structure (but StackOverFlow won't allow me to show it so I did just put the link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Bundle-ClassPath` in your MANIFEST.MF, this is required to tell Eclipse where to look for object code. It should be something like:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
   lib/jdom-2.0.6.jar
```

In the MANIFEST.MF editor you can set this on the 'Runtime' tab in the 'Classpath' section.